# Can we add specific condition in @Retryable for any exception in spring-retry?

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-retry

I have a class which has @Retryable annotation added to method with value as custom exception and maxAttempts =2 .

```
  @Override
  @Retryable(value = CustomException.class, maxAttempts = 2)
  public void process(String input) {
    //code logic
}
```

Currently this code is retried everytime there is a CustomException thrown in application but my code throws this CustomException in different ways like :

1. throw new CustomException(CustomErrorCode.RETRY)
2. throw new CustomException(CustomErrorCode.DONOTRETRY)

I want to retry CustomException which has errorcode Retry.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add conditions based on the exception properties; however, in the retryable method, you can do this:

```java
RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().setExhaustedOnly();
```

This prevents any retries.

```java
/**
 * Signal to the framework that no more attempts should be made to try or retry the
 * current {@link RetryCallback}.
 */
void setExhaustedOnly();
```